# Where can I find joomla header file

Tags: php, joomla

Where can I find Joomla header file?

I know header file is being called inside template->index.php file like,

```
 jdoc::include type="head"/>
```

But I want to know the exact file/path for the header file in joomla.

Comment: Please dont start editing this file. It's a core Joomla file and therefore should not be touched. If you want to make changes to it, you should create a small plugin calling action before anything is rendered.

Comment: If you want to customize jdoc:include type=head part, then this [LINK](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/tutorials/joomla/36-customize-the-jdoc-include-type-head-part.html) might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not hack core files, ever. Besides the possibility that you introduce a vulnerability the file, with your changes, will be overwritten when Joomla is updated. Sure, you can avoid updating but then you have to personally fix any vulnerabilities that are discovered and then fixed in future releases, or run a install with a known vuln.

*Don't hack core files.*

Why don't you tell us what it is you are trying to achieve? Why do you want to modify the content of head? There are, no doubt, far better ways to do it than modifying head.php.